# JSON objects filter

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to json and facing one issue to filter.

i have below json;

```
var data =[
   {
      "year":2015,
      "month":1,
      "total_sales":123
   },
   {
      "year":2015,
      "month":2,
      "total_sales":212
   },
   {
      "year":2015,
      "month":3,
      "total_sales":602
   },
   {
      "year":2015,
      "month":4,
      "total_sales":918
   },
   {
      "year":2015,
      "month":5,
      "total_sales":920
   },
   {
      "year":2015,
      "month":6,
      "total_sales":167
   },
   {
      "year":2015,
      "month":7,
      "total_sales":922
   },
   {
      "year":2015,
      "month":8,
      "total_sales":162
   },
   {
      "year":2015,
      "month":9,
      "total_sales":678
   },
   {
      "year":2015,
      "month":10,
      "total_sales":312
   },
   {
      "year":2015,
      "month":11,
      "total_sales":895
   },
   {
      "year":2015,
      "month":12,
      "total_sales":470
   },
   {
      "year":2016,
      "month":1,
      "total_sales":962
   },
   {
      "year":2016,
      "month":2,
      "total_sales":501
   },
   {
      "year":2016,
      "month":3,
      "total_sales":115
   },
   {
      "year":2016,
      "month":4,
      "total_sales":193
   },
   {
      "year":2016,
      "month":5,
      "total_sales":199
   },
   {
      "year":2016,
      "month":6,
      "total_sales":169
   },
   {
      "year":2016,
      "month":7,
      "total_sales":482
   },
   {
      "year":2016,
      "month":8,
      "total_sales":197
   },
   {
      "year":2016,
      "month":9,
      "total_sales":375
   },
   {
      "year":2016,
      "month":10,
      "total_sales":497
   },
   {
      "year":2016,
      "month":11,
      "total_sales":692
   },
   {
      "year":2016,
      "month":12,
      "total_sales":868
   },
   {
      "year":2017,
      "month":1,
      "total_sales":292
   },
   {
      "year":2017,
      "month":2,
      "total_sales":602
   },
   {
      "year":2017,
      "month":3,
      "total_sales":744
   },
   {
      "year":2017,
      "month":4,
      "total_sales":248
   },
   {
      "year":2017,
      "month":5,
      "total_sales":549
   },
   {
      "year":2017,
      "month":6,
      "total_sales":694
   },
   {
      "year":2017,
      "month":7,
      "total_sales":793
   },
   {
      "year":2017,
      "month":8,
      "total_sales":436
   },
   {
      "year":2017,
      "month":9,
      "total_sales":752
   },
   {
      "year":2017,
      "month":10,
      "total_sales":852
   },
   {
      "year":2017,
      "month":11,
      "total_sales":588
   },
   {
      "year":2017,
      "month":12,
      "total_sales":807
   }
]
```

And i want to reduce it in below format;

```
var data = [
   {
      "month":"january",
      "2015":123,
      "2016":962,
      "2017":292
   },
   {
      "month":"february",
      "2015":212,
      "2016":30,
      "2017744 602 },{ "      month":"march",
      "2015":212,
      "2016":30,
      "2017":20
   }   ....
];
```

What has been tried so far:

```
var uniqueYears = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (uniqueYears.indexOf(data[i].year) === -1) {
        uniqueYears.push(data[i].year);
    }
}
var uniqueMonths = [];
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (uniqueMonths.indexOf(data[i].month) === -1) {
        uniqueMonths.push(data[i].month);
    }
}
var attributelist = [];
console.log(data.length);
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var as = $(data).filter(function(i, n) {
        console.log(n) return n.month === uniqueMonths[i]
    });
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Do you think StackOverflow is a help desk?  Not trying to be snarky, but if that's what you think, it isn't

Comment: This "question" reads like you just want us to do your work for you.  Put some effort in and show us what you tried.

Comment: var uniqueYears = [];
for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++){    
    if(uniqueYears.indexOf(data[i].year) === -1){
        uniqueYears.push(data[i].year);        
    }        
}
var uniqueMonths = [];
for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++){    
    if(uniqueMonths.indexOf(data[i].month) === -1){
        uniqueMonths.push(data[i].month);        
    }        
}   
var attributelist = [];
console.log(data.length);
for(i = 0; i< data.length; i++){    
 var as=$(data).filter(function (i,n){
  console.log(n)
   return n.month===uniqueMonths[i]
  }); 
}

Comment: @DanielD i have tried this one, but while push into array it took only one sales column

Comment: @GeorgeJempty stuck on the issue its the only one reason for posting here

Comment: @AmitShinde edit your question and paste your code there.  code in comments is not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a predefined array with objects for each month and then iterate the given array of objects and assign the found total value to a month item with the year as key and total as value.

```js
var array = [{ year: 2015, month: 1, total_sales: 123 }, { year: 2015, month: 2, total_sales: 212 }, { year: 2015, month: 3, total_sales: 602 }, { year: 2015, month: 4, total_sales: 918 }, { year: 2015, month: 5, total_sales: 920 }, { year: 2015, month: 6, total_sales: 167 }, { year: 2015, month: 7, total_sales: 922 }, { year: 2015, month: 8, total_sales: 162 }, { year: 2015, month: 9, total_sales: 678 }, { year: 2015, month: 10, total_sales: 312 }, { year: 2015, month: 11, total_sales: 895 }, { year: 2015, month: 12, total_sales: 470 }, { year: 2016, month: 1, total_sales: 962 }, { year: 2016, month: 2, total_sales: 501 }, { year: 2016, month: 3, total_sales: 115 }, { year: 2016, month: 4, total_sales: 193 }, { year: 2016, month: 5, total_sales: 199 }, { year: 2016, month: 6, total_sales: 169 }, { year: 2016, month: 7, total_sales: 482 }, { year: 2016, month: 8, total_sales: 197 }, { year: 2016, month: 9, total_sales: 375 }, { year: 2016, month: 10, total_sales: 497 }, { year: 2016, month: 11, total_sales: 692 }, { year: 2016, month: 12, total_sales: 868 }, { year: 2017, month: 1, total_sales: 292 }, { year: 2017, month: 2, total_sales: 602 }, { year: 2017, month: 3, total_sales: 744 }, { year: 2017, month: 4, total_sales: 248 }, { year: 2017, month: 5, total_sales: 549 }, { year: 2017, month: 6, total_sales: 694 }, { year: 2017, month: 7, total_sales: 793 }, { year: 2017, month: 8, total_sales: 436 }, { year: 2017, month: 9, total_sales: 752 }, { year: 2017, month: 10, total_sales: 852 }, { year: 2017, month: 11, total_sales: 588 }, { year: 2017, month: 12, total_sales: 807 }],
    grouped = [{ month: 'january' }, { month: 'february' }, { month: 'march' }, { month: 'april' }, { month: 'may' }, { month: 'june' }, { month: 'july' }, { month: 'august' }, { month: 'september' }, { month: 'october' }, { month: 'november' }, { month: 'december' }];

array.forEach(function (o) {
    grouped[o.month - 1][o.year] = o.total_sales;
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```